# WSImport - Maven - Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a maven class in Intellij 12, and I have some generated classes using wsimport. Maven can generate and compile the classes without a problem.  However, when I go to deploy the WAR, I get an error saying that the package containing the generated class is not found.  Looking at the code that references the generated class, it says "cannot resolve symbol".

Can someone give me suggestions on where to look for the error?  It doesn't seem maven-related, rather it seems more to do with my Intellij setup.

Thanks.

Comment: I just don't know what a maven class is. Which 'wsimport' are you talking about? Part of some tool? Did you look inside the WAR and along the classpath to see if the class it wants is present?

Comment: Where are the generated classes being *put*? If they're not in a place Maven normally looks for Java source files they won't be in the final artifact. E.g., generated sources have a known location in the Maven standard directory layout, and their generation should be part of the normal build process.

Answer (score 0):

Add package witch contains generated class as package dependency in IntelliJ.

> Right Click on project and go to open module settings, Select module
>   from opening window, go to dependency tab. add that package as
>   dependency.

Comment: It's an issue w/ generated source, not Maven dependencies.

Comment: @DaveNewton I had similar issue and i solved the way what i tolled in my answer

Comment: OP specifically states they're generated classes, not a Maven dependency: they're not in a repository.